# Make blog secret during design construction

Tags: customization

I am a n00b at wordpress. I'd like my blog to be secret while I finish the design. How do I do this? 
Thank you!

Comment: Simply download and install a maintenance plugin and activate it. There are a couple on wordpress.org that you can download. I would also advice you to setup a local test site on your pc for developing purposes. Xammp works well for me

Answer (score 2):

You can use htaccess to disable public access.
in your .htaccess file add this.

```
AuthName "Secure Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/htpasswd/file/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require valid-user
```

don't forget to change htpasswd address in this.
You can create .htpasswd from here.

http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/htpasswd-generator/

Comment: I think this might be a bit to much for a noob. Great idea, but I think a plugin would be enough. Don't like to edit files unnecessaryly

Comment: Well actually it prevents everybody to access website including search engings as well as spam bots. Also htaccess is not a core file so there is nothing wrong in editing that. I always use htaccess to for development website. And never use a plugin when you can do something with couple of lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

thats easy.

I use a Pluing for this "Private Only"

Go to add new plugins section and search for it.

or visit its plugin site [Private Only](https://wordpress.org/plugins/private-only/)

Have fun & good luck with your blog

Note: I have no affiliation with this plugin :-)

Comment: It will be nice if you post a link to the plugin. Also, please state your affiliation

Comment: what do you mean with "state your affiliation" ?

Comment: Do you have any affiliation with the plugin

Comment: No I don't. Just what I did when i wanted to hide my blog.

Comment: Ok, then you just add the following to your answer `Note: I have no affiliation with this plugin` :-)